# F# error FS0191: 'inherit' declarations may not have 'as' bindings

Tags: f#

This error happened after updating to latest may 2009 CTP. Sometimes I do not get the meaning of some error messages. I write this code:

```
type MyClass = class
    inherit Game as base
```

and I receive this error message:

> error FS0191: 'inherit' declarations
>   may not have 'as' bindings. The
>   keyword 'base' may be used instead.
>   Remove this 'as' binding

I deleted **as base** from second line

```
type MyClass = class
    inherit Game
```

and program compiled fine (is it that simple?). But, I keep wondering if this would have some unexpected effects. Hence my questions:

Is it "may not have 'as' binding" or "cannot have 'as' binding" or "should not have 'as' binding"? What is the meaning of that error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did the right thing.  Once upon a time, if you wanted to refer to the base class, you had to do the 'as base' thing (and could choose any identifier).  Now 'base' is a keyword for referring to the base class, and the 'as base' syntax was deprecated and then removed.

(And you're right, it should say 'cannot' instead of 'may not', I'll go fix that right now.)

Comment: Thanks. But, you know, What confused me was "...The keyword 'base' may be used instead."   I went to MSDN and read that the keyword base is available in derived classes and refers to the base class instance. It is used like the self-identifier. So, I thought, it must go somewhere, maybe I should write  inherit base Game, but that popped another error, so finally I removed completely. Any more info you would like to share?

Comment: Thanks, that's useful feedback to help improve the error message.